# QTP flex plugin

Tags: automation, qtp

I am using QTP 11 now, but when I do some test on the webpage which uses Flex, the QTP cannot work on that, it cannot detect anything on the webpage. What plugin can I use to make the QTP work on this? And how to get it, Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For **QTP 11** there is a Flex addin supplied by Adobe (see [pdf documentation from Adobe](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/testing_with_QTP_flex3.pdf)).

Starting with **UFT 11.50** (**UFT** is **QTP+Service Test** as a single product) the Flex addin is built in and comes with the installation.